# jQuery clone is not working when draggable elements create cloned copy

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery Draggable functionality, I need to create drag and drop functionality by cloning the drag element and dropped to a specified position.
Here is my code

```
 $(function () {
             $('#Draggable' + Localvar + '').draggable({
                 snap: true,
                 helper: 'clone',

             }
                 );
             $('#Droppable').droppable({
                 accept: $('#Draggable' + Localvar + ''),
                 drop: function (event, ui) {
                 }
             });
         });
```

Code creates a clone and it is draggable but it can't drop.

Comment: Maybe it's because you have an error in your code: accept: $(#Drag') should be accept: $('#Drag') (needs a single quote before #

Comment: No, I changed but its not working

Comment: There are two $(#Drag), both with errors. Have you fixed them?

Comment: look at your console and debug the errors first (press f12 and click on the console tab)

Comment: I edited my code . please look

Answer (score 0):

You should take a basic JS course to understand why you need to quote strings, what are selectors and how to use them.

Here is a basic setup of your code, notice the `"` wrapping the selectors.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#Drag").draggable({
    snap: true,
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#Droppable").droppable({
    accept: $("#Drag"),
    drop: function (event, ui) {
      alert('dropped');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-widget-content { 
  width: 60px; 
  height: 60px; 
  padding: 0.5em; 
}
.ui-widget-header {
  width: 60px; 
  height: 60px; 
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="Drag" class="ui-widget-content">Drag me</div>

<div id="Droppable"  class="ui-widget-header">Drop here</div>
```